# How do I fix this animation glitch?

Tags: css

I made a spinning cube with HTML/CSS, and these triangles keep appearing above the cube, as shown below. Is there any way to fix this?

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.w1 {
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.cube {
  font-size: 4em;
  width: 2em;
  margin: 1.5em auto;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(-22.5deg) rotateY(45deg);
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  animation: spin infinite 5s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.side {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  
  background: rgba(tomato, .6);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
}

.front  { transform:                  translateZ(1em); }
.top    { transform: rotateX( 90deg)  translateZ(1em); }
.right  { transform: rotateY( 90deg)  translateZ(1em); }
.left   { transform: rotateY(-90deg)  translateZ(1em); }
.bottom { transform: rotateX(-90deg)  translateZ(1em); }
.back   { transform: rotateY(-180deg) translateZ(1em); }

@keyframes spin {
  0%   {transform: rotateX(-22.5deg) rotateY(45deg);}
  100% {transform: rotateX(-22.5deg) rotateY(405deg);}
}
```

```html
 <body>
  <div class="wrapper w1">
   <div class="cube">
    <div class="side  front"><img src="https://cdn.glitch.com/2f5f53d3-f3c1-4dd2-a2ef-ae82302f3cd4%2Fplanks_oak.png?v=1609955268179" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
    <div class="side   back"><img src="https://cdn.glitch.com/2f5f53d3-f3c1-4dd2-a2ef-ae82302f3cd4%2Fplanks_oak.png?v=1609955268179" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
    <div class="side  right"><img src="https://cdn.glitch.com/2f5f53d3-f3c1-4dd2-a2ef-ae82302f3cd4%2Fplanks_oak.png?v=1609955268179" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
    <div class="side   left"><img src="https://cdn.glitch.com/2f5f53d3-f3c1-4dd2-a2ef-ae82302f3cd4%2Fplanks_oak.png?v=1609955268179" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
    <div class="side    top"><img src="https://cdn.glitch.com/2f5f53d3-f3c1-4dd2-a2ef-ae82302f3cd4%2Fplanks_oak.png?v=1609955268179" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
    <div class="side bottom"><img src="https://cdn.glitch.com/2f5f53d3-f3c1-4dd2-a2ef-ae82302f3cd4%2Fplanks_oak.png?v=1609955268179" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
   </div>
   </div>
 </body>
```

A screenshot of the cube:
[image: the cube]
These triangles keep appearing above the cube during the animation and I have no idea why.

Comment: Please add browser/system information!

Comment: `backface-visibility:hidden;`on `.side`should help. looks like a typical chrome side effect :)

Comment: that did help, thanks! :)

Comment: If you add absolute URLs to your image files that would help us!

Comment: @martin https://cdn.glitch.com/2f5f53d3-f3c1-4dd2-a2ef-ae82302f3cd4%2Fplanks_oak.png?v=1609955268179
It's a 16x16 image

Answer (score 0):

So I messed around with the CSS and apparently the border on `.side` was the thing causing those triangles. I removed it and am no longer seeing the triangles.
[image]

Comment: backface-visibility also works : https://jsfiddle.net/csvrjt38/1/